# Symfony Crawler - how to read the current element's type

Tags: symfony, web-crawler

i don't know how i could read the current html element's (instance of Crawler class) type.
For example:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
    <div>
        <p class="message">Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello Crawler!</p>
    </div>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$type = $crawler->getType(); // it should return 'div' but such method doesn't exist
file_put_contents('log.txt', $type, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
$crawler->nodeName
```

In your specific case, if youre using branch any branch up to 2.5:

```
$crawler->filter('body')->children()->getNode(0)->nodeName
```

If you are using master branch, you can do it a bit more elegantly:

```
$crawler->filter('body')->nodeName()
```

Symfony Crawler tries to 'fix' your HTML and packs it into `html>body` tags if they don't exist. I don't know if it's possible to disable this feature.

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler::$nodeName

Comment: @Pierre I expanded my answer